# Fragment content in activity not properly sized

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am using fragments in an activity with a `BottomNavigationView` and out of the box I noticed the `fragment` content goes below the `BottomNavigationView`

**This is the fragment in Android studio before inflating it in the activity:**

[image: this is the fragment in Android studio before inflating it in the activity]

**The app after the fragment has been inflating:**

[image: the app after the fragment has been inflating]

Here is my fragment `XML` I read on other posts on this site that I needed to use the `CoordinatorLayout` as parent and add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the first child but it didn't work.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  android:layout_margin="16dp"
  tools:context="com.brigafrica.koyako.fragments.SendFragment">




<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:text="@string/amount_to_send"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/edtAmountToSend"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:digits="0123456789.,"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/appCompatButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.095" />


<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/appCompatButton"
    style="@style/AppTheme.RoundedCornerMaterialButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="@string/send"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />



    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: post your MainActivity `xml` code

Answer (score 0):

What is necessary to identify the problem is your activity XML content and how you are managing the fragments in your activity.

The simplest way to think is that the fragment is just a content that will be displayed in a piece of your activity, and you should provide the correct information about the dimensions of this piece in your activity.

**Explaining with my example**

An activity called *MainActivity* that has one *ViewPager* and one *BottomNavigationView*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="newidea.com.br.bottomnavigationexample.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main.viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The ViewPager is the piece where the fragment will be displayed in MainActivity, so I have to tell the activity that the ViewPager can not invade the BottomNavigationView space, if not the fragment content that will be displayed in the ViewPager will goes below the BottomNavigationView.

**How to do that ?**

In my example I configured the ViewPager with this:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

It means that the ViewPager width and height matchs the parent's width and height, the ViewPager top is aligned with the parent's top, and it is a layout above the BottomNavigationView, so the ViewPager can not invade the BottomNavigationView space.

What you need to understand is that doesn't matter what is in your fragment, what really matter here is the dimensions configuration of the ViewPager, because the ViewPager will display the fragment.

[Full example with 3 fragments, each one with a Button in the Bottom](https://github.com/fabiomirgo/bottomnavigationexample)

[Fragment in Android Studio before inflating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zySsd.png)

[The app after the fragment has been inflated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJJ7W.png)